# Unable to update Jquery because unable to find the compatible jquery.ui.core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am working on visual studio 2012 mvc project. I just did a Updates package through tools > nuget package manager > manage nuget packages for solution > nuget.org > update all. everything looks all right but finally I got an error:
updating 'jquery 1.4.4' to 'jquery 2.1.1' failed. unable to find a version of 'jquery.ui.core' that is compatible with 'jquery 2.1.1'

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all extensions by using nuget and reinstall them.